# How to get rid of syntax error that arises with multiple single quotation marks in the command

Tags: python, terminal, single-quotes, quotation-marks

I have a command to obtain the last logged in time of a certain ubuntu user and I need the output to store it elsewhere so when I run this in my python script, I get a syntax error but when I `ssh` into remote server and execute the command, there's no problem.

```
# last logged in time of ubuntu user

user_login = os.popen('ssh -i /Users/abcxyz/keypair ubuntu@1#.###.##.# lastlog -u 'ubuntu' | grep -v Latest | awk '{$1="";$2="";$3="";print $0 }'').read()

print(user_output)
```

when I just run this in my terminal, it works fine and gives me the output:

```
ssh -i /Users/abcxyz/keypair ubuntu@1#.###.##.# lastlog -u 'ubuntu' | grep -v Latest | awk '{$1="";$2="";$3="";print $0 }'
```

Output: `Sat Nov 17 16:32:10 +0000 2018`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your string has both single and double quotes inside of it, I'd triple-quote the whole thing

```
user_login = os.popen("""ssh -i /Users/abcxyz/keypair ubuntu@1#.###.##.# lastlog -u 'ubuntu' | grep -v Latest | awk '{$1="";$2="";$3="";print $0 }'""").read()
```

Otherwise as written some of the single quotes inside your string are terminating the full length string in the middle

Comment: Works perfectly well for the immediate problem; the only reason I don't suggest this is that it leaves other issues open (f/e, shell injection attacks) as soon as the user wants to parameterize a command that they specify in this way.

Answer (score 1):

**Ideally**, you should construct this in a manner that doesn't expose you to the problem at all -- which is to say, let the Python interpreter do the work of generating a correctly shell-quoted string (and then re-quoting it to be safely passed to ssh).

```
try:
  from shlex import quote # Python 3
except ImportError:
  from pipes import quote # Python 2
import subprocess

# specify your commands the way they're actually seen by the operating system -- with
# lists of strings as argument vectors.
rmt_pipeline = [[ 'lastlog', '-u', 'ubuntu' ],
                [ 'grep', '-v', 'Latest' ],
                [ 'awk', '{$1="";$2="";$3="";print $0 }' ]]

# ...then, let shlex.quote() or pipes.quote() determine how to make those lists be valid
# shell syntax, as expected by the remote copy of sh -c '...' invoked by ssh
rmt_pipeline_str = ' | '.join(' '.join(quote(word) for word in piece)
                              for piece in rmt_pipeline)

# ...finally, generate the argument vector for our local copy of ssh...
ssh_cmd = [ 'ssh', '-i', '/Users/abcxyz/keypair', rmt_pipeline_str ]

# and actually invoke it.
user_output = subprocess.Popen(ssh_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
```

If you **really** want to use `os.popen()` -- which you shouldn't, as Python documentation [explicitly suggests using `subprocess` instead](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen) -- you can replace the last line with:

```
ssh_cmd_str = ' '.join(quote(word) for word in ssh_cmd)
user_output = os.popen(ssh_cmd_str)
```

---

On UNIX-family operating systems, all program execution happens through the `execve()` syscall, which passes a list of C strings around. Specifying that list yourself gives you the most possible control over how execution takes place, and prevents shell injection attacks (where a user authorized to provide a parameter to one of the programs you're running passes content that's interpreted by the shell as syntax rather than data, and thus runs a completely different program or an indirection operation instead).

Comment: thanks so much  for sharing the code & detailed explanation :) appreciate it.